# Configure Jenkins for a angular project - single git repo with multiple packages

Tags: node.js, git, angular, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to configure a jenkins job for angular project present inside a git repo of multiple angular projects.

```
MyProjectRepo
  -project-1
  -project-2
  -project-3
   ...
  -readme.md
```

All of the above projects are available in a private npm registry.
this is something similar to angular packages like common, core, http etc., Can we configure a job for a specific project and once built should be published to the npm registry.
Restricting the projects to a single repository because managing too many repo will be more difficult.

Comment: In the Jenkins job configuration you could 'cd' into the say project-1 one as an initial job step and then build the code as you require. You should also be able to parameterize the Jenkins job if you want to pass in the working directory you wish the 'cd' into

Comment: Yes. you are right. That's how we did it.